# Create X train and Y Train for CSV dataset in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

i would like to ask about creating x_train, y_train and x_test, y_test on CSV has been split into two between data_train.csv and data_test.csv

Comment: if you already have data split into test and train data, you can use your data_train.csv for the training data and data_test.csv for the test data.

Comment: I agree with what topsail said, but what is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a general question, but I can answer with:

You can use following block to import these csv files in your env.

```
import pandas as pd # for CSV file I/O operations
train = pd.read_csv('../input/data_train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('../input/data_test.csv')
```

I did not see your .csv files but it must be:

```
# x is features, y is your target column
x_train = train.loc[:,1:] 
y_train = train.loc[:,0]

x_test = test.loc[:,1:] 
y_test = test.loc[:,0]
```

So, you can obtain the x and y values, if it is not working please open your .csv and parse the coordinates accordingly :)